# How to extend the first postulate of statistical thermodynamics to reach Gibbs postulate?

Tags: mathematical-physics

### Question

I'm searching for the derivation which enables me to say:

> The first postulate of statistical thermodynamics can be extended to
>   arrive at the Gibbs postulate, a postulate which relates the energy of
>   said microstates to internal energy of a system as calculated by
>   classical thermodynamics

-[wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistical_Thermodynamics_and_Rate_Theories/Postulates_of_Statistical_Thermodynamics#First_Postulate_of_Statistical_Thermodynamics)

### Motivation

> Gibbs's Postulate is one which relates the internal energy, $U$, of a
>   system as determined by thermodynamics to the average ensemble energy,
>   $E$, as determined by statistical mechanics. $$ U = \langle E \rangle $$

-[wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistical_Thermodynamics_and_Rate_Theories/Postulates_of_Statistical_Thermodynamics#First_Postulate_of_Statistical_Thermodynamics)

What is this average exactly? For say, the quantum harmonic oscillator is it:

$$ U = \langle E \rangle= \langle \psi |H| \psi \rangle $$

Where $H$ is the Hamiltonian and $\psi$ is the wavefunction. The partition function on the other hand makes no explicit reference to the wavefunction of the system as it uses [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)#Canonical_partition_function).

P.S: Feel free to limit to an example to that of the quantum harmonic oscillator.

[Cross-posted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516329/how-to-extend-the-first-postulate-of-statistical-thermodynamics-to-reach-gibbs-p)

Comment: Ask this question on physics.stackexchange.com. Most people here are just mathematicians

Comment: Questions of these sort get downvoted there :/

Comment: I don't see why they would. But oh well.